# Is it possible to rotate the screen on an M1 or M3 iMac?

Tags: display, imac, settings, apple-silicon

The option to rotate the screen has disappeared from the Display settings.

After much searching, I have not found a definitive answer:

**Is it possible to rotate the screen on the new iMacs?**

I'd like to use mine upside down.

**[updated]**

The result using Vakror Alor's answer:

[image]

An upside-down iMac M3 with a VESA mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some applications, like [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay/releases/tag/v2.0.11), have an  option to rotate the screen. Strangely, when the screen is rotated, the setting reappears, as you can see in this image:

[image: rotation settings]

However, this setting does not appear when the screen is not rotated.

Tested on an M1 Macbook air 8G of ram, 128G storage. MacOS 13.4 (22F66)

Answer (score 1):

I have an external display that shows a Rotation setting, and if I change the value, then the file:
`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.displays.plist`

is modified. It contains an XML key for Rotation.

[image]

Modifying the contents may have the desired effect. You may need to reboot to update any changes.

There is a similar file in the user Library:
`~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.displays.64281A00-E2B6-5261-9E70-A674227508B4.plist`

the filename presumably including some sort of ID number for the hardware.

Comment: This information combined with the chosen answer will hopefully enable me to create a script to rotate the screen without a special app. Thanks!